# MSBuild Errors while building VSTO Addin's

Tags: visual-studio-2013, vsto, office-2013

I recently migrated my VSTO Add in projects from "VS2008 and office 2007" to "VS2013 and office 2013", Changes took place as  below settings.

1. .Net Framework version from 3.5 to 4.5(While upgrading project).
2. I have added VSTO 2013 PIA assemblies to reference.

That's it, when i tried to compile i have faced below MSBuild errors.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\OfficeTools\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.targets(268,13): error MSB4064: The "TargetFrameworkVersion" parameter is not supported by the "SignFile" task. Verify the parameter exists on the task, and it is a settable public instance property.
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\OfficeTools\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.targets(264,9): error MSB4063: The "SignFile" task could not be initialized with its input parameters.
```

and i have tried to find solutions over the internet but couldn't find much, Any Solutions for this problem will be helpful.

Comment: i have created a seperate brand new project in VS2013 and added code to it but still ended with the same MSB4063&MSB4064 error.

What's wrong.
and I have built an empty ExcelAddin Proj. which is created in VS2013 and i haven't changed anything, yes nothing but still facing same MSBuild errors.

Comment: Did you have any luck resolving this issue? I just ran into it as well.

Comment: @Erick T , i have changed all the office Dll references from office 2007 to office 2013 and rebuild worked like a charm for me..... check if there any older version office Dll's referenced, make sure that you refer any single version throughout the add-in, using multiple versions can cause this problem. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks - I actually ran into a slightly different issue that I eventually fixed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was not the MSBuild, **

> i have updated visual studio update 3 to update 4

and started working like charm.

I think Microsoft guys have moved something around from Update 3 to update 4 but this has been reported several times in many forums and i don't know why they have not mentioned it but this is one effective solution.

Comment: Updating to VS2013 Update 4 solved it for me as well.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this issue. The problem is that Update 3 of Visual Studio 2013 moved some things around, so you need to use the MSBuild that is now installed with Visual Studio 2013 (or the [standalone build tools](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40760) for build servers). You need to make sure that you're using the correct MSBuild (currently at C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\Bin), and it should work.

http://datatoknowledge.com/2015/01/30/vsto-and-visual-studio-2013-update-3/

Erick

Comment: You, my friend, are a genius!

Answer (score 2):

This is still not working as of Visual Studio 2015 Update 3.

I had to actually modify the C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\OfficeTools\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.targets file and remove the TargetFrameworkVersion attribute from the SignFile task.